# can i make my scraping (pandas read html) script faster?

Tags: python, pandas, performance

i have a very simple script, it just scrapes some tables off the internet and inserts it into a db. however: tickerlist contains about 8000 rows. and the script takes about 2 hours to complete (80ms per ticker). is there anyway to speed it up?

this is my code:

import pandas as pd
import weslib as wl
from datetime import datetime

```
wl.joblog('AQstats', '', '','Starting AQ scrape stats')
con = wl.condb()

tickerlist = wl.tickerlist(['NASDAQ','NYSE'])
#tickerlist = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'T','INTC']

scrapedate = datetime.now()

for n, stock in enumerate(tickerlist):
    wl.joblog('AQstats', stock, '','Starting: ' + str(n+1) + '/' + str(len(tickerlist)) + ' ' + str(stock))
    try:
        url = 'https://www.alphaquery.com/stock/' + str(stock) + '/all-data-variables/'
        df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
        df['numvalue'] = wl.convertnumbers(df[1])
        df['scrapedate'] = scrapedate
        df['symbol'] = stock
        df.columns=['Label','orgvalue', 'numvalue','scrapedate','symbol']
        df.reset_index(inplace=True) 
    except (Exception) as error:
        wl.joblog('AQstats', stock, '','error: scraping \n' + str(error) )
        continue

    try:
        wl.insert_values(con,df,'AQstats',stock,'AQstats')
    except (Exception) as error:
        wl.joblog('AQstats', stock, '','error: scraping \n' + str(error) )
        continue
        
con.close()
wl.joblog('AQstats', '', '','Ending AQ scrape stats')
```

and these are the two relevant functions from my own lib.

```
import psycopg2 as db
import psycopg2.extras as extras
def insert_values(conn, df, table, ticker, call):
    """ Using psycopg2.extras.execute_values() to insert the dataframe """
    df.replace('None',0,inplace=True)
    # Create a list of tupples from the dataframe values
    tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.to_numpy()]
    # Comma-separated dataframe columns
    cols = ','.join(list(df.columns))
    # SQL quert to execute
    query  = "INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES %%s on conflict do nothing" % (table, cols)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        extras.execute_values(cursor, query, tuples)
        conn.commit()
    except (Exception, db.DatabaseError) as error:
        joblog(call, ticker, table, "db error: %s" % error)
        print("DB Error: %s" % error)
        conn.rollback()
        cursor.close()
        return 1
        joblog(call, ticker, table,"insert values done for: %s %s", call, ticker)
    cursor.close()



def joblog(job, ticker, table, note):
    print('JOBLOG', job, ticker, table, note)
    conn = condb()
    query = "insert into log (logdate, logtable, logjob, logticker, note) values ( current_timestamp, %s, %s, %s, %s ) on conflict do nothing" 
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(query, (table, job, ticker, note))
    except (Exception, db.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(query)
        dblog(job, ticker, 'log' ,"DB Error: %s" % error)
        conn.rollback()
        cursor.close()
        return 1
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: You cannot do anything in your code about the amount of time that it takes for alphaquery dot com to reply back with data. You might possibly be able to set it up to make several data requests simultaneously, but this might not help for several reasons - chiefly, the website might rate-limit you, and the problem could be to do with your internet connection. That said, what actually is the purpose of the database in this code? What overall task are you trying to perform with the data?

Comment: this is import daily data job, the script scrapes the eod data adds to the db store. any analyses will be done on selects from the database. my intet connection is 100mbit so that shouldnt be a problem. how would i set up asynchronous requests?